# Unable to access Modelmap in JSP using EL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I am passing a LinkedHashMap`<String, Object>` from the controller to the View(JSP).

I am not able to iterate through the map and display the values in the Object.

The Object here is my custom POJO class which contains appStatus, dbCon, mwCon, timeStamp etc...

When the map is empty no row should be created. The no of rows created should be equal to the entries in the map. However, no rows are created though there are entries in the map..

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HealthController {
    public static Map<String, Object> statusMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
    public ModelAndView statusDisplay() {
        . . . 
        . . .
        return new ModelAndView("monitor", statusMap1);
    }
}
```

monitor.jsp

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

        <tr>
            <th>Gateway</th>
            <th>Application Status</th>
            <th>MW Connection</th>
            <th>DB Connection</th>
            <th>Solace Connection</th>
            <th>Last Updated Time</th>
        </tr>

    // check if map is empty
    <c:if test="${!empty statusMap1}">
        <c:forEach var="statusObj" items="${statusMap1}">
            <tr>
                <td>${statusObj.appName}"</td>
                <td>${statusObj.appStatus }</td>
                <td>${statusObj.mwCon }</td>
                <td>${statusObj.dbCon }</td>
                <td>${statusObj.solCon }</td>
                <td>${statusObj.timeStamp }</td>
             </tr>
        </c:forEach> 
    </c:if> 

</table>
```

also tried with

```
<td><c:out value="${statusMap1.statusObj.appName}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${statusObj.appStatus }" /></td>
```

but din't work

Comment: have you tried to set your class type in the Map instead of object ?? like `public static Map<String, YourClass> statusMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, YourClass>();`

Comment: Yes. I did try with LinkedHashMap<String, CustomClass> but dint work.

Comment: also tried with <td>${statusObj.key.mwCon }</td> but nothing seems to work

Comment: Check generated HTML output.

Comment: the forEach loop is generated in the HTML. I assume the problem is with JSTL as I am able to print the values of the map without looping over it. I have included  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> in the JSP and my maven dependency as <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>. Am I missing on something?

Comment: Please do not use [java] tag on questions about problems which are not reproducible using a plain Java application class with `main()` method. You have a JSP/Spring MVC problem, not a Java SE problem.

Comment: @DeepthaAS Did you try the solution I mentioned bellow?

Answer (score 0):

To the `ModelAndView` constructor you are passing a **view name** and a **map** of your POJO.

But what you should be passing is a **view name** and a **model**(which in turn is a map) and then you should put your map(or better a List) of your POJO into the model and access it in the jsp.

Code:

```
@Controller
public class HealthController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
    public ModelAndView statusDisplay() {
        . . . 
        . . .
        List<YourPojoType> pojos = new LinkedList<YourPojoType>();
        . . .
        //Add objects to the list here
        Map<String, Object> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("statusList1", pojos);
        return new ModelAndView("monitor", model);
    }
}
```

Then in jsp instead of:

```
<c:if test="${!empty statusMap1}">
<c:forEach var="statusObj" items="${statusMap1}">
```

you should have:

```
<c:if test="${!empty statusList1}">
<c:forEach var="statusObj" items="${statusList1}">
```

P. S.

If you want to keep using map. Remember that when iterating over a map in for each loop `statusObj` is of type `Entry<String, Object>` so to get value one should use `${statusObj.value.mwCon}`